# HTML tag <a> Both href and onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on this project and I'm really stuck on 1 thing: I would like to make a submenu with all sub-pages in one html file.

Whenever I use both `href` and `onclick` it does not work.

It only works when I change the `href` into "#", but that would make the page inaccessible from other pages.

Please note that changing the return value of the function does not help.

Thanks so much in advance!

Here is my HTML:

```
<script>
function show(shown, hidden, hidden2) {
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
  document.getElementById(hidden2).style.display='none';
  return true;
}
</script>

<ul>                
<li><a href="../info/index.html" onclick="return show('Page1','Page2','ṕage3');">Doelstelling</a></li>
<li><a href="../info/index.html" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1','ṕage3');">Bestuur</a></li>
<li><a href="../info/index.html" onclick="return show('Page3','Page1','ṕage2');">Lid worden</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="Page1" style="display:none">
<a href="#" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1','ṕage3');">Bestuur</a></br>
<a href="#" onclick="return show('Page3','Page1','ṕage2');">Lid worden</a>   </br>
<p>

text

</p>

</div></br>

<div id="Page2" style="display:none">
<a href="#" onclick="return show('Page1','Page2','ṕage3');">Doelstelling</a>    </br>
<a href="#" onclick="return show('Page3','Page1','ṕage2');">Lid worden</a></br>
<p>

text

</div></br>
  <div id="Page3" style="display:none">
<a href="#" onclick="return show('Page1','Page2','ṕage3');">Doelstelling</a>  </br>
<a href="#" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1','ṕage3');">Bestuur</a></br>
    <p>
text
 </p>

</div></br>
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return false;` doesn't help you because an error triggers before this line of code.

Take a look at your `show` function call: you pass `'ṕage3'` as a third argument, and then you do `document.getElementById(hidden2).style.display = ...`. But you don't have an element with id="ṕage3".

Replace `'ṕage3'` with `'Page3'`, and this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You need to return false in your OnClick.
Since you are calling `show` in your onclick, return false instead of true.

```
<script>
function show(shown, hidden, hidden2) {
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
  document.getElementById(hidden2).style.display='none';
  return false;
}
</script>
```

When the user clicks on the anchor (the  tag) it will first execute the onclick. If the onclick returns false it will stop. If the onclick returns true, then it will continue with the default behavior and change the window location to the value of the href attribute.

Comment: I have tried that, but that does not change anything in this situation.

Comment: Ah, yes, because you have a typo in the onclick's where you're using `ṕage3` instead of `Page3` and `ṕage2` instead of `Page2`. This would cause an error in the JavaScript when it attempts to get the elements by id and they do not exist. --update: looks like Curious already pointed that out though :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the default event handling in the JavaScript with event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("a").click(function()
{
  alert(1);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.com">Text</a>
```

Don't use `onclick` in 2015.